How can I improve this MySQL query that groups data into new columns?
I have a set of data that looks like this:

I want to summarize the total counts per year into new columns like this:

So that I can then create a chart that looks something like this:

This is the SQL query that I came up with, and it works but it's fugly and I cannot figure out a better way to do it. I'm basically creating 3 different SELECT queries that group the data then JOIN them together into one result set
SELECT t1.year,t1.google_users,t2.yahoo_users,t3.hotmail_users  FROM 

(SELECT year, sum(num_users) AS google_users
FROM emailstats 
WHERE email_provider='google'
GROUP BY year) AS t1

LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT year, sum(num_users) AS yahoo_users
FROM emailstats
WHERE email_provider='yahoo'
GROUP BY year) AS t2
ON t1.year=t2.year

LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT year, sum(num_users) AS hotmail_users
FROM emailstats 
WHERE email_provider='hotmail'
GROUP BY year) AS t3
ON t1.year=t3.year

ORDER BY t1.year

The real project (and the data & queries) are more complex than this. I simplified it for the purposes of discussion. Would appreciate suggestions on how to improve and simplify it.
